# Fill select element using Angular based on query string parameter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, query-string, asp.net-web-api

I need to fill select element with data retrieved from web api

I use attribute routing for web api

```
api/project/{pid}/users
```

It works fine, if when pass parameter pid manualy.

I need to pass parameter through querystring using angular $http.get()

I tried this

```
this.getItems = function () {
   return $http({
        url: '/api/project/{pid}/users',
        method: 'GET',
        data: $.param({pid:123})
    });

}
```

In fiddler I got 404 error.

```
http://localhost/api/project/%7Bpid%7D/users
```

I read about $location.$Search and $routParam, but I need additional help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Angular will not parse the string and replace {pid} like in views, so you could simply do:

```
this.getItems = function () {
   return $http({
        url: '/api/project/' + pid + '/users',
        method: 'GET'
    });
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
this.getItems = function () {
   return $http.get('/api/project/' + pid + '/users');
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works when I manually pass pid. But how to catch pid from query string? I assume that  I need to do this  in angular controller?

Comment: I think you need to explain a bit more in detail what you mean by "catch pid from query string".

Comment: That's it.  I used $location service to get pid from query string.
`var pid= $location.search();` And following code above. Tnx

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with "passing pid manually"?

I'm quessing that you have something like `ng-click="getItems()"` in your html. You could just change that to `ng-click="getItems(pid)"` and pass it to your function

```
this.getItems = function (pid) {
   return $http.get('/api/project/' + pid + '/users');
}
```

The `params` option would add a search object to the end of you url like

```
?users=jondoe
```

UPDATE

Looking at your new code everything looks good. But in you HTML it should be

```
<select ng-model="user" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users" ng-click="getUsers(item.id)">
```

Also, the function should be

```
$scope.getUsers(pid) {
                dataFactory.getUsers(pid)
                    .success(function (user) {
                        $scope.users = user;
                    })
                    .error(function (error) {
                        $scope.status = error.message;
                    });
            }'
```

Comment: "passing pid manually" = hardcoded :)
I have select element in HTML. I want to call function on change event and pass pid parameter from query string.

Comment: ok. then just try to pass it with your ng-click as shown above.

Comment: if the pid changes with a user input you can use ng-change. Could you provide a jsfiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I need to call controller function when user choose exact option in select element.

Angular Service:

```
dataFactory.getUsers = function (pid) {
            return $http.get(urlBase + 'api/projects/project/' + pid +'/users');
```

Angular Controller:

```
function getUsers(pid) {
                dataFactory.getUsers(pid)
                    .success(function (user) {
                        $scope.users = user;
                    })
                    .error(function (error) {
                        $scope.status = error.message;
                    });
            }'
```

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="user" ng-options="item.id as item.name for item in users" ng-click="getUsers(pid)">
```